# PHP insert values select from

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain me what is wrong with that part of code?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1".
"(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ".
"VALUES('$1','$2','$3','$4','$5')".
"SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='213' LIMIT 1 ";
```

Return me that error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='' LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: You're running two SQL statements in one command. You can't do that, unless you're using mysqli_multi_query. You'll need to make separate database calls.

Comment: Even with multiquery it's pretty messed up. Try `echo $sql` and see for yourself.

Comment: Please learn SQL first. There are a lot of websites to help you with that.

Comment: Also, the error message doesn't match the query. It's usually best to show the *actual* code.

Comment: And for the love of all that is holy change your table and column names

Comment: @allen213 Judging by the error message they're just placeholders.

Comment: @Juhana we can only hope

Answer (score 1):

You shoud execute first `insert` , and then your `select`,separate them :

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) VALUES('$1','$2','$3','$4','$5')";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='213' LIMIT 1 ";
```

and execute them independently.

Comment: And for the love of all that is holy change your table and column names

Comment: ty my friend for tour response. I will try that !

Answer (score 1):

Here,
you are executing multiple queries.

try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1".
"(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ".
"VALUES('$1','$2','$3','$4','$5');".
"SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='213' LIMIT 1 ";
```

see the ; in between the sql statements.

And use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php multi query.